# SSIS Script component input

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS package with a C# script component. The script processes some documents and extracts information to several SQL tables. Combining the tables is not an option. The script runs perfectly aside from taking a long time to process all the files. Each file contains the date they were last modified, my solution is to store that date in a SQL table and then the next time the package is run to retrieve the previous dates and compare. If a file has not been modified then the date will be the same and the file skipped.

Unfortunately I am unable to figure out how to bring in the SQL table. The connections and script component settings appear to be correct but my C# code does not work. Ideally I would like to bring the table in as either a dictionary or list. The table itself consists of only two columns: file name, last modified date.

Comment: check the third link i provided in my answer. i think this is exactly what you are lokking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Add a `Execute SQL Task` in which you select all data from the Date Table

   ```
   Select * From [Table]
   ```
2. Store the result in a Object Variable by selecting it as  `ResultSet`
3. Then load this variable inside the script

For more information, read the following detailed articles:

- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)
- [Map Result Sets to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141689(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [SSIS - How To Read Object Type Variable In Script Task [Script Task SSIS]](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-read-object-type-variable.html) *This article contains a very similar example*
- [Using Variables in the Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task)

Comment: This solution is perfect. I had to change this:
`Dts.Variables["User::VarObject"].Value`
to this:
`this.Variables.Variable_name`